# Using Jitterbit for cooperative work

Tags: jitterbit

Our team started to work on integration Jitterbit with other our systems and we faced with such issue - how better to organize cooperative work in Jitterbit Studio on the same project for few developers? We saw that pretty often we got problems due to conflicts when we worked together on interrelated components.

Are there any approaches how we can maximally to distantiate job of our teammates in Jitterbit working on the one project? Are there any integrated abilities to fork and merge Jitterbit projects (or part of them)? Maybe, there are exists some other approaches or features?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spent some time for investigating this question and designed such workflow:

1. The team have one common project where we store all project's elements (scripts, operations, transformations etc)
2. Each member has his own copy of common project where he works on his part of functionality (I didn't find how easily clone projects, so I used for this "Export/Import as Jitterpack" functionality)
3. When developer want to merge his work with other's or take something from common project to his copy he use "Import Project Data" functionality.

In such case we can be sure that teammates don't affect each other and common project contains all completely implemented features together. But I see here some minuses:

1. There is no easy way for versioning and backups of components (we can export project periodically, but IMHO its sucks).
2. When we import Project data, items with same names is not updated, but each time it's created with new name, if such name already exists.

It's not critical minuses, but it may be the cause of potential errors. If someone know how better to deal with it please share your experience!